# What causes the following downcast failure?

Tags: c#

I attempted to down cast `Animal` to `Dog` but it fails. What causes this failure?

```
class Animal
{
    private readonly string name;
    public Animal(string name) => this.name = name;
    public virtual string Greet() => $"Animal's {name}";
}

class Dog : Animal
{
    public Dog(string name) : base(name) { }
    public override string Greet() => $"Dog's {base.Greet()}";
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Animal a = new Animal("Hello World");
        Dog d = a as Dog;

        if (d == null)
            Console.WriteLine("Cast failed.");
        else
            Console.WriteLine(d.Greet());
    }
}
```

Comment: You can only cast an object to something that it implements. `Animal` does not implement `Dog`, so this does not work.

Comment: I never do down casting but today I attempted to teach others about it and I got surprised apparently my understanding is wrong about what down casting mean. I thought that down casting is a process of casting a parent to a child. :-) get smarter every day.

Comment: You can do `Animal a = new Dog("Rover");`, however, if you want to "up-cast"

Comment: @RufusL: Yes of course. But I am talking about down casting.

Comment: `Animal` to `Dog` is up-casting, not down-casting.

Comment: @RufusL: Down casting is from `Animal` to `Dog`. In addition, sub classes are also derived from a base class, so the direction is downward.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195474/discussion-between-rufus-l-and-money-oriented-programmer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because a is an animal and not a dog. You instantiated an animal.

Following will work (creating a dog instance instead of an animal):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Animal a = new Dog("Hello World");
        Dog d = a as Dog;

        if (d == null)
            Console.WriteLine("Cast failed.");
        else
            Console.WriteLine(d.Greet());
    }
}
```